# full calendar 2 is not extending the event bar(month mode) to the next day even though the event timing of the previous day crosses 12 am

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar 2.

for ex, I am creating a event which start from may 29 2014 8:00pm and ends at may 30 2014 3:00 am

but if you switch the mode to month view its not extending the event bar to 30 may.

the event bar is getting extended only if the difference between start time and end time is greater than 15 hours.

i even checked on the following link

http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-2.0.0-beta2/demos/agenda-views.html

same is reflecting there

but this feature is working on previous versions.

Please help me on this i have almost completed everything with this fullcalendar2.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Share your demo url in JSFiddle or as a code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new parameter '[nextDayThreshold](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/)' which sets what the minimum events ending time must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day. The default is 9am, so any event with an ending time before that will only be render on the previous day. 
You could set it to '00:00:00' to have similar behavior as v1.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, If you add 09:00 AM for 30th March is get extended, If you are not specifying  the time, its understand as 12:00 AM if you are not specifying anything, there is some setting in month view to change this to be extended.

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

{
    title: 'Fine Trip',
    start: new Date(y, m, 29, 20, 00),
    end: new Date(y, m, 30, 09, 00)
}
```